# 34 Inch Ultrawide for Business - Light Gaming

Tags: monitors

Can anyone recommend a budget/value 34inch 4k monitor mostly for business but also some light strategy gaming.

Also, do I need anything else? Like a 4K HDMI cable?
Will it function with a typical business laptop? (probably integrated graphics, can they drive 4k?)

Anyone have any experience going up to a 34inch for coding and work? I've read its amazing on blogs, but curious if its worth the price tag.

Thanks for the help.

LM

Comment: I've found that for eye candy's sake, 2K about does it for me. I happen own and code with a 4K resolution laptop and the step up between 2K (like the microsoft surfaces) and 4K is less dramatic for me than 1080p to 2K. If you'd like I can include a 2K monitor so you can compare price. Also what location would you like these monitors to be available at (US, UK, etc.)?

Comment: Thank you for responding. If you think 2K would be just as OK for a 34inch I'm willing to go with that.

Comment: So any thoughts on value 34inch 1440 monitors?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally said 2K earlier when I meant 1440+ ("2.5 K") monitors. At this diagonal monitor size, you might as well go for 4K monitors. I can recommend you a monitor you could purchase online today if you tell me your location (should I assume you are from the US?).

Comment: Could you add some information about the room the monitor will be standing in? Some budget monitors have low brightness or don't have antiglare which might not be suitable for bright rooms or if there are windows opposite the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an owner of Viotek GN34C that has a 1440x3440 resolution I can say that it is really amazing and a huge upgrade from 1080 and from standard 16:9. It is very easy to open two programs or web pages side by side, without running into all sorts of weird layout issues that you get on a 16:9 monitors. Definitely worth it.

Other than Viotek I can suggest you to look at something like Samsung CF791, Samsung C34J791 or Microboard M340CLZ, as they all have WQHD VA panels manufactured by Samsung and might be cheaper depending on your location, but keep in mind that original Samsung monitors use Quantum Dot technology, which other similar monitors don't have.

You would need a DisplayPort cable to make use of the 100Hz refresh rate, though, or at least HDMI 2.0 to run it at 60Hz.

If you are going to be using it with a modern business laptop you shouldn't see any problem with running programs in WQHD, but it would struggle to run modern games with decent FPS.

Comment: Wow, awesome, thank you so much for the advice.Question, what is a good sale price for this monitor, or does it ever go on sale?

Comment: @LargeMarge If you like the monitors that have been recommended, you can find the cheapest prices for them with [PC Part Picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/monitor/#xcx=0).